# Getting a div to show up on the exact spot of a full screen map irregardless of screen size/proportions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to mark down seaports in the form of small 15px/15px circles (span elements) on a 100% height, 100% width relative to screen size background (map of Europe). Unfortunately when I give them a position of absolute and specify their alignment using percentages, they seem to move around the map when the proportion/screen size changes.

**Is there any way to get around this and force them to be in the exact same spot of the map irregardless of screen size/position?**

If it's of any relevance the background is set using the background property and the image is of an .svg format. I'm also changing the background-size to 1000% and setting it's position using the background-position property.

Comment: Can you please show some code and/or a demo?

Comment: With a background image this is hard. With an actual image it's a lot easier - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/dgcha

Comment: If you could post an example of your code it would help